# Sending information from a bash script to a program

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe

I'm making a bash script to send commands to a launched program, the only way I founded on internet was through [named pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash).

Is there an easier way to do it all inside the same script? Because named pipes have the problem that I must have 3 scripts, one for managing the program, other sending the information from the main and then the reader to parse the information to the program (If I correctly understood the above link).

And that is a problem as the manager has to call the others because I need the reader to recieve an array of files as input and I found no way of doing so, if you know how please [answer this other question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240151/passing-an-array-as-command-input)

Thank you

--- 26/01/2012 ---

After Carl post I tried

```
#!/bin/bash

MUS_DIR="/home/foo/dir/music"

/usr/bin/expect <<-_EOF_
spawn vlc --global-key-next n $MUS_DIR
sleep 5
send 'n'
sleep 5
send "n"
_EOF_
```

But it doesn't work, it just spawns vlc but it doesn't skip the song

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [`expect(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/).

Comment: Why did you nest your expect script inside the bash script?  I tried here (with Mac VLC) and it doesn't appear to take input from stdin at all - are you sure you're trying to do something that's even possible?

Comment: Because I need to continue using the bash commands later in the script, if you launch vlc --global-key-next n in terminal (at least in ubuntu) and then press n it skips the songs, so yes I suppose it accepts stdin...

Answer (score 0):

More details about the program you want to communicate with would be useful.

Essentially you just need some sort of inter process communication. Files/pipes/signals/sockets could be used. Write to a specific file in the script and then send an interrupt the program so it knows to check the file, for example.

Depending on your language of choice, and how much time you can spend on this/how big this project will be. You could have the launched program use a thread to listen on a port for TCP packets and react to them. Then in your bash script you could netcat the information, or send an HTTP POST with curl.

Are you sure it's not possible for the application to be started by the script? Allowing the script to just pass arguments or define some environment variables.

Comment: I'm new in bash scripting so I'm not sure of anything, the program I want to communicate with is vlc, I want to launch it, then ask the user to enter some input, and send the choices to the program. For example if the user press 'n' send a command to vlc to change to the next song. Thanks for the kindness

Comment: I'm also new in the stackoverflow forum so I didn't know if you received the notification of the last comment as I didn't mentioned your name :S